# C#: How to create a SplashScreen in Xamarin/XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I've finished my first app in `xamarin` forms with C#/XAML for Android.

Finally I want to add a SplashScreen to my app (now it is the White by default) and I want to add the logo of the app at center of SplashScreen.

How could I do it in XAML?
I do know nothing about how to do this...

Comment: I changed  many aspects of the question and reformulated the title.

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/